# Mathematica not showing normally on high resolution computers

Tags: front-end

So I have a Windows 10 laptop with 1920*1080 resolution. On this computer it automatically sets the programs running on it to show at 150% size. But however Mathematica does not supports this well, and so the letters end up blurred. Like this:

[image]

Notice how "a,b,c,d" appear much less sharp than the "Mathematica 11.3".
So how can I maintain the benefits of high resolution?
I did try the method in the  "possible duplicate", but it doesn't really solve my problem. The UI is not too small, but it's just too blurry for this screen DPI. The compatibility setting in windows does not really help much, as although the menu gets normal, letters in the cell appear just the same as before. Also, disabling the magnify pretty much breaks everything-all of the elements in documentation is dislocated, making it totally unusable. 
As of update 1703, there is no longer a way to disable the magnify for a single application anymore.

Comment: Regarding your statement at the bottom: This is not true. The DPI scaling settings do still exist (there are even more)

Comment: Mathematica is blurry on all high res displays (except Mac)

Comment: I'm surprised you have this issue on a standard FHD-resolution screen. Are you using a custom DPI setting on your PC? Usually this problem rears its ugly head on high-DPI displays (4K and such), and for those there is no solution. Mathematica simply does not support such displays at this time, and that's the end of it. I know Wolfram is working on the issue, but I doubt you'll see any improvement before the next major release (12.0), if then. So my guess is another year or so, perhaps, if we're lucky.